# Univariate- Variance preserving, order reversing transformation

Tags: variance, data-transformation, quantiles

This is a soft question: How can the order of a sample univariate data be reversed while preserving the variance?

Comment: Multiply the observations by $-1$.

Comment: That theoretically works-$(Constant)^2VAR(X)$. I have data that are always $\geq 0$ and would like them to remain positive. It is okay  if you would like to propose a transformation i.e an approximation in terms of the variance preserved but the rank order has to be exactly reversed.

Comment: Multiply the observations by $-1$ and add a large constant.

Comment: There are literally an uncountably infinite number of different ways to do this - transform your data by any monotonically decreasing function and then scale it appropriately so that the variances match. Perhaps you can explain what the purpose is here and it may become clearer what transformation is appropriate.

Comment: The key is that Var(aX+b) =a^2 Var(X).  So you just need to make sure a^2 =1.  We all have given good answers, but everyone did it as a comment only.  Are we to refrain from making an answer if the question seems trivial?

Comment: That assume only a linear transformation @MichaelChernick. I didn't post mine as an answer because the question seemed so broad I figured there must be something more to it, so I thought I'd wait for clarification.

Comment: @macro Each of the above answers given were linear transformations.  My statement was intended to make that transparent. I didn't say that a linear transformation is the only way to preserve the variance.  But I am ahrd pressed to think of another transformation that would work for any distribution with a finite variance.  Do you have something in mind?  Even one that is distribution dependent.

Comment: You can do particular examples. For example if $X_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $$Y_i = e^{-X_i} \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{(e^{\sigma^2} - 1) e^{\sigma^2}}}$$ reverses the ordering and preserves the variance. A linear function would also work, of course. The best choice probably depends on the context, so some clarification from the original poster is needed.

Comment: @Michael Sometimes answers emerge within comment threads; e.g., someone writes "did you mean this?" and the original proposer responds "yes, that's a good answer!" In such cases the site encourages someone--anyone--to formulate an actual reply. It's ok even for a newbie to come along and just summarize what's in the comments; nobody frowns on that. It's preferable to not having any answers. Here, we're still at the stage of wondering just what the heck is being asked: does this question refer to a *random variable* or to a dataset? Can the transformation depend on the observations or not?

Comment: @whuber Often I make very innocuous comments and you take them as criticism.  i was just stating a fact and not trying to be critical at all about any change in direction of the question. In fact I added a comment on my own work with stationary sequences that is tangentially related to the question.

Comment: @ All- I must agree that the question was quite open-ended, and there were views that were both trivial and non-trivial. I have appended the question now-based on the discussion. Thank you for the views posted above- though I must indeed agree that the initial question was a bit too short and that made it quite open-ended. Do look at the updated question now and please let me know-if I have missed something critical in the present formulation which is in a multivariate setting. Thank you.

Comment: I am a little surprised that you took my response to your question as criticism, @Michael. You had asked "Are we to refrain from making an answer if the question seems trivial?" and, in my role as a moderator and knowing you are relatively new here, I felt obliged to reply. I am sorry if there was *anything* in that reply, however minor, that could be construed as critical of you (or any other part of this thread): no criticism was intended. Now--returning to the question--VPH, I am puzzled about what you might mean by the "variances of the return matrix."  Could you please explain?

Comment: Sure- Changed that phrase @whuber into rank order of the "variances of the columns of the return matrix". Is there something still that can lead to a lack of clarity-let me know and I shall rephrase.

Comment: @Macro.  Thanks for the example.  I suspected that it would have to be distribution dependent.

Comment: @whuber I was not taking your remark as criticism of me.  I just thought you were misinterpreting my remark as being critical of the sute's procedures. I was not and I just wanted you to know this. I also think that this type of misinterpretation has happened more than once. I am not being critical of you and I was not offended by anything.  I am just trying to clarify what I meant.

Comment: @Michael - That example was distribution dependent, but you can do the same kind of trick with any decreasing function by scaling by the ratio of the sample standard deviations - this will make the sample variances match exactly. I'm not sure I understand the modified question though..I'll have to think about it

Comment: So for example I guess you could make Y=1/X  for say a non-negative rv Xand then multiple Y by a constant C>0 that will return the variance to the variance of X.  Taking C/X reverses the order of the observed values.

Comment: @Michael How can-this ensure preserving the rank order of the variances of all the columns in the return matrices $R(X)$ , $R^*(X)$-after the transformation of $X$ into $X^*$? I believe that you meant to multiply $Y$ by a constant $C > 0$ such that the variance is matched with the variance of the column in R-instead of the variance of the column in X?

Comment: @VPH No my understanding was that it reverses the order of the observations and that we are looking at one distribution and so the constant C is used to make that variance the same as for the univariate distribution presumably the marginal distrbution for the time series.  I don't remember seeing that there were k time series and I had to apply one transformation that will preserve the variance of all of them.  In that case the reciprocal will reverse order the values but if the variances are different one constant will not fix all of them.

Comment: Did you make a major change to the formulation of the problem? I think I was still address the original problem that I thought only involved one series.  All the old answers seem to address the problem with one time series.  My response was addressing Macro's comment and not a new fomrulation of the problem.  If this is a new problem I think it would have been better to introduce it as a separate problem rather than replace the original one.

Comment: @Yes it is a multivariate formulation-I would post this as another question